# How do I tell Visual Studio that my header should be C++ and not C?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have a C++ project, and the main file with the main function is a `.c`, but when I include my `.h` that is supposed to be C++, I think I am getting errors because it thinks it is C. How can I tell it that my header should be C++ and not C, like my main?

Comment: The header file will use the context of the source that includes it.  You can tell a C++ file to compile with a C context using `extern C`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `#include` C++ header in a C source file. A header is not compiled separately. All that `#include` does - it makes the compiler work as if the header was a part of the file.

Comment: Is there a way I can tell the program to use another C++ file that is not my main to grab all those functions?

Comment: Of course. Just create C++ source file, #include the header in it, and insert the source file in Visual Studio project.